# Simple 2 column div layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a very simple 2 column layout with floating `div`'s in html. The problem is that the following `div`, `foot` is always being rendered to the right of the `right` div. I know I should be using a `clear` statement somewhere, but I'm not sure which is the proper spot.

Also, as you can see in left I've explicitly specified the height of `left`. Is there a way to set force `right` to be of the same height without specifying it again?

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left" style="float: left; width: 150px; background: #DDDDDD; height: 500px;"> 
        left column
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="float: left; background: #EEEEEE;">
        right column
    </div>
</div>

<div id="foot">
    footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `clear:both` on the `foot` div.

For your second question, you can set the `main` div to have a particular height, and then set the height of `left` and `right` to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS should look like this:

```
 #foot{
   clear: both;
 } 
 #left, #right{
   float: left; // remove this definiton from tag 
   height: 500px; // remove this definition from tag
 }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#foot{display: block; clear: both;}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, you need more and also, `div's` are naturally `block`

Answer (score 0):

The `foot` div should be cleared.

```css
#foot { clear: left /* or both */; }
```

As for the equal heights challenge, I recommend you use the [faux-column technique by Roger Johansson](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/).

Bear in mind that the main column must have more content than the secondary one. If that's the case, it removes the 500px height constraint and is flexible to whatever you might want.

Answer (score 0):

create a empty div and put it at the end of right div just above the end of main div and give it class name of clrbth ..

in css you may add this property to the class

```
.clrbth {
clear:both;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```